# Ruby Regex gsub - everything after string

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a string something like:

```
test:awesome my search term with spaces
```

And I'd like to extract the string immediately after `test:` into one variable and everything else into another, so I'd end up with `awesome` in one variable and `my search term with spaces` in another.

Logically, what I'd so is move everything matching `test:*` into another variable, and then remove everything before the first `:`, leaving me with what I wanted.

At the moment I'm using `/test:(.*)([\s]+)/` to match the first part, but I can't seem to get the second part correctly.

Comment: I don't know if ruby regex supports look-behind. try this `(?<=test:)(\S*)(\s+)(.*)` so group1 is `awesome`, group3 is the rest text

Comment: If you have never used rubular, you will  quite enjoy it. http://rubular.com/r/lVg99vlTCE

Comment: Thanks, I was just testing with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first capture in your regular expression is greedy, and matches spaces because you used `.`. Instead try:

```
matches = string.match(/test:(\S*) (.*)/)
# index 0 is the whole pattern that was matched
first = matches[1] # this is the first () group
second = matches[2] # and the second () group
```

Comment: How would I the use this to put the matches into variables?

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
/^test:(.*?) (.*)$/
```

That is, match `"test:"`, then a series of characters (non-greedily), up to a single space, and another series of characters to the end of the line.

Comment: How would I then use this to put the matches into variables? Sorry for the n00bish question - arriving to Ruby from PHP and just finding my way around.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to remove all the leading spaces before the second match too, hence I have \s+ in the expression.  Otherwise, remove the \s+ from the expression, and you'll have what you want:

```
m = /^test:(\w+)\s+(.*)/.match("test:awesome my search term with spaces")
a = m[1]
b = m[2]
```

http://codepad.org/JzuNQxBN